# Using the DynamicMethod for scripting

Tags: c#, scripting

This is described in the article [C# scripts using DynamicMethod](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CSSDemo.aspx)
Pluses I see - the first call will occur much faster than using CSharpCodeProvider.

What are the disadvantages of this method?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "disadvantages"? To some degree, advantage/disadvantage depends on how you wish to use it! What do you want to use it for? I can think of a handful of disadvantages, but before I answer, I guess I want a bit clearer explanation of the question.

Comment: I want to use C# for scripting in their applications. I can use the DynamicMethod  or CSharpCodeProvider for the purpose. I would like to make an informed choice CSharpCodeProvider vs DynamicMethod.

Comment: Are you looking for an example of where you can dynamically execute c# code from within c#? (Asking this question because of one of the responses)

Answer (score 3):

I just finished reading the source code of [C# Scripts using DynamicMethod](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CSSDemo.aspx)

I think the most intolerant disadvantage is: tooooooooooo complex. In .Net 4.0, we could use DLR and ironpython to do scripting with 5% lines of code as using DynamicMethod. DLR is newer and it is the trend.

some code example for DLR and IronPython:

```
var scriptEngine = Python.CreateEngine();
var scriptSource = scriptEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(@"# coding=utf-8
def execute(command):
    exec(command)
");
scriptScope = scriptEngine.CreateScope();
scriptSource.Execute(scriptScope);
dynamic execute = scriptScope.GetVariable("execute");
execute("print 'hello world'")
```

pseudo code only, you'd have to modify the above code in order to compile and run. I wrote the above code to show you how easy it will be if you use DLR and Ironpython instead of DynamicMethod.

Comment: C# or VB are much more common languages ​​than IronPython. I would like to use C# for their scripting.

Comment: They are all .NET languages. not so different as you think

Comment: Can you give an example for the DLR and C#?

Comment: IronPython is pretty dramatically different from C# or VB.NET. The fact that they all ultimately execute against the same runtime does not in any way mean that someone who is familiar with C# will be able to pickup and use IronPython right away. The article alex mentioned is offering to do exactly that in a scripting form.

Answer (score 1):

DynamicMethod requires writing IL directly. The author of the article has apparently written his own compiler to translate C# scripts into IL that can be loaded into the DynamicMethod, but that is likely to be very fragile. CSharpCodeProvider uses csc, the same compiler that runs in Visual Studio ([almost](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ed_maurer/archive/2008/06/11/a-tale-of-two-compilers.aspx)), so it is likely to be a lot more reliable.

Comment: But with CSahrpCodeProdvider you get an assembly not a DynamicMethod. [Four years ago](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/May/13/DynamicMethod-from-C-code) it was not possible to create a DynamicMethod from a string of code, but the article OP linked to provides an option.